# Delayed post parameters when submitting via onChange in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, onchange

I'm trying to send a parameter to the api to give me an exact json response, but when i'm trying to submit my form via select onChange={onAddSubmit}, it is still passing the default value 146846 but I already changed my select to 146847 so i'm getting the invalid response.

Home.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Api from "../Api";

import AppContainer from "../tmp/AppContainer";
import HomeContainer from "./HomeContainer";

const Home = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [allValues, setAllValues] = useState({
        contractId: "146846",
        planId: "1028",
        dateStart: "2021-01-30",
        dateEnd: "2021-01-31",
        numberOfAdults: 1,
        numberOfChildren: 0,
        planOption: "Individual",
        unit: "day",
    });
    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setAllValues({ ...allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const onAddSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            await Api.getCurlPost({
                ...allValues,
            }).then((response) => {
                const result = response.data;
                setPosts(result.data);
            });
        } catch {
            alert("Failed to add post!");
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        onAddSubmit;
    }, []);

    return (
        <AppContainer>
            <HomeContainer
                onAddSubmit={onAddSubmit}
                changeHandler={changeHandler}
                loading={loading}
                posts={posts}
            />
        </AppContainer>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Here is my **HomeContainer.js** that contains my html and bootstrap design

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPlane } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faCircleNotch } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

class HomeContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        const { onAddSubmit, changeHandler, loading, posts } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row mb-auto">
                    <div className="col-md-6 p-2">
                        <img
                            width="100%"
                            src="../resources/img/starr/7437.jpg"
                        />
                        <div className="mt-3 shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                            <h3 className="text-center">
                                <FontAwesomeIcon
                                    icon={faPlane}
                                    rotation={0}
                                    style={{ marginRight: 5 }}
                                />
                                Travel Details
                            </h3>
                            <form onChange={onAddSubmit}>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <select
                                        className="form-control"
                                        name="contractId"
                                        onChange={changeHandler}
                                    >
                                        <option value="146846">
                                            TravelLead Domestic Travel Insurance
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="146847">
                                            TravelLead International Travel
                                            Insurance
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <select
                                        className="form-control"
                                        name="planId"
                                        onChange={changeHandler}
                                    >
                                        <option value="1028">
                                            Economy (Single Trip)
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="1029">
                                            Elite (Single Trip)
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </form>    
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HomeContainer;
```

Comment: Not sure (can't test now), but I think it's because you are using onChange, instead of onSubmit. Maybe it's triggering Form onChange before select onChange

Comment: yes it is working when I used <button type="submit"> and <form onSubmit={onAddSubmit} /> it reflects the default or what I changed in my form when I click my button, but what I want is when I change any of my input type it sends the parameters to the api and give the response right away, but right now it is not working my allValues not reflecting the changes when it is submitted using my onChange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it already, I just added allValues as a parameter when calling onAddSubmit on my useEffect hook, and if there is something changes happen to allValues list it will automatically submit a request to the API and throw a response.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        onAddSubmit(allValues);
    }, [allValues]);
```

And onAddSubmit function, just change the **...allValues** to **...data** on api parameter that sends a request to axios.

```
const onAddSubmit = async (data) => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            await Api.getCurlPost({
                ...data,
            }).then((response) => {
                const result = response.data;
                setPosts(result.data);
            });
        } catch {
            alert("Failed to add post!");
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };
```